# How to retrieve coded values (domain) from Runtime geodatabase?

Tags: domains, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios, swift

I am working with the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS 10.2.5 (not the latest version) in order to create an iOS app, using swift coding.

I have created a runtime geodatabase which includes coded values and I cannot find a way to retrieve them.

I checked the ESRI documentation for this version but I could not find something about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I found the solution. It is done using the AGSCodedValueDomain.

For further details check: https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/10-2/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_coded_value_domain.html